# How to get size of a second to Last Element of List<string> c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

i'm searching the best way to get size of a second to Last Element of string List. Any suggestions? Thank in advance

```
List<string> ZipFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(textBox1.Text, "*.zip", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                 .Where(x => File.GetLastWriteTime(x) >= startDate 
                                          && File.GetLastWriteTime(x) <= endDate)
                                 .Select(x => Path.GetFileName(x))
                                 .ToList();
```

I tried the following code, but obviously it does not work: it break!

```
string secLast = LastZipFiles.ToList<string>()[LastZipFiles.ToList<string>().Count - 2];
```

Comment: What happens if there's only a single entry?

Comment: show an error message if there's only a single entry

Comment: What do you mean by that? Actually `throw` an exception, write to console, error log, output to a text box? Either way, there's answers below that you can easily tailor.

Answer (score 0):

```
var secLast = ZipFiles.Reverse().Skip(1).First();
```

Assuming there *is* a second to last. And it's not very efficient.

Better might be:

```
if(LastZipFiles.Count > 1)
{
  var secLast = LastZipFiles[LastZipFiles.Count -2];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. Can I use size at the same time as count?

Comment: @R.Van I'm not sure I understand your question. The `.Count` property is the number of elements in the list. There is no `size` property.

Comment: i want to get in a selected folder that contains zipfile, the size[KB] of last element and second to last element in a list<string> ZipFiles to compare each other. The last must be bigger than the secLast. I don't know if I am well understood

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your comment to the previous answer, I see you actually want the file size. You should create a FileInfo from the file name and access it's Length property:

```
var secondToLastFileSize = new FileInfo(ZipFiles[ZipFiles.Count - 2]).Length;
var lastFileSize = new FileInfo(ZipFiles[ZipFiles.Count - 1]).Length;
```

Comment: @ Ciprian i get this Exception: LastZipFiles[LastZipFiles.Count].Length : 0; threw an exception of types  System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException. and the size is always null.

Comment: i've also tried something like your updated answer, but it break again telling: An unhandled exception of type System.ArgumentOutofRangeException occurred in mscorlib.dll Additional information: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

Comment: It means your collection of filenames is empty, or has only one result. You can perform a check before trying to get the file size.

Comment: It's weird because I have 3 zip files in my collection of ZipFiles